# variable of type id

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I have this code to add obstacles sprite nodes as childs to the `concreteGround` node:

```
-(void) addObstaclesToNode:(NSString *)pattern
{
    for(int index = 0; index<[self getPattern:pattern].arrayOfSprites.count; ++index)
    {
        id o = [[self getPattern:pattern].arrayOfSprites objectAtIndex:index];
        o.position = CGPointMake(o.position.x + windowW, o.position.y);
        [concreteGround addChild:[[self getPattern:pattern].arrayOfSprites objectAtIndex:index]];
    }
}
```

(`getPattern` is a method I created to return an object in an array) Anyway, I want the variable `o` to receive `[[self getPattern:pattern].arrayOfSprites objectAtIndex:index]`, but that code can return various types of object. I used `id` to do so, but when I try to access a property of the object, Xcode tells me that "the property was not found on the object of type id". Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 3):

To your Q:

There is a big chaos in Objective-C related to declared properties. (Lattner was there?)

For the dot notation, even it does not say anything about the way the property and its accessors are implemented (synthesize or explicit) and declarared (@property or method declarations) the compiler does not accept any known property, but only properties of objects with known type.

You can do two things:

1. Do not use dot notation for the access. (This is valid, if the method is declared anywhere.)
2. Downcast the object.

BTW: Your code is not very Objective-Cish. You can use fast enumeration and indexed subscripting to make it better readable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to make sure `o` is an instance of a class that supports that selector, or that it supports the selector.

```
if ([o isKindOfClass:[YCYourClass class]]) {
    YCYourClass *yourClass = o;
    yourClass.position = ...
}
```

Or:

```
if ([o respondsToSelector:@selector(setPosition:)]) {
    [o performSelector...
}
```

Although, now that I think about it, you may have just forgot to include the header where you declare the interface that has the `position` selector... that may work too.